# Detecting if an element of a list is multiword

Tags: python

This code works and all but I am not 100% sure how it works as it is in a Python book I borrowed. I don't understand how the program checks if something is multiword. Also what do the starred lines mean

```
places= ["Home","In-n Out Burger", "John's house", "Santa Monica Pier", "Staples center",  "LA Dodgers stadium", "Home"]
def placesCount(places):
    multi_word = 0
    count = 0
    **while True:
        place = places[count]**
        if place == 'LA Dodgers stadium':
            break
        **if ' ' in place:**
            multi_word += 1
        count += 1
    return count + 1, multi_word + 1

placesCount(places)
```

Answer (score 1):

The method checks if a string in the list `places` has a space, it considers that a multi-word.

If the list `places` contains the string `LA Dodgers stadium`, the method will return the position of the string, plus a count of how many multiple words were found before it.

Here's a hint: What happens when you pass in `['LA Dodgers stadium']` to the function? Does it return the correct numbers?

```
def placesCount(places):
    multi_word = 0 # a count of how many multiple words were found
    count = 0 # an initializer (not needed in Python)
    while True: # start a while loop
        place = places[count] # get the object from the places list
                              # at position count
        if place == 'LA Dodgers stadium':
            # quit the loop if the current place equals 'LA Dodgers stadium' 
            break
        if ' ' in place:
            # If the current string from the places list
            # (which is stored pointed to by the name place)
            # contains a space, add one to the value of multi_word
            multi_word += 1
        # Add one to count, so the loop will pick the next object from the list
        count += 1
    # return a tuple, the first is how many words in the list
    # and the second item is how many multiple words (words with spaces)
    return count + 1, multi_word + 1
```

Comment: if ' ' in place:
            # If the string in place contains a space, add one to the value   I DONT UNDERSTAND HOW it detects if has a SPACE

Comment: IS THEIR ANY WAY HOW TO FIND THE SPACE without using the find method. I need to complete my program without using the find method

Comment: What find method are you talking about?